Find the measurement of the $\angle PSQ$ in the semicircle below
If $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{PNQ}  = 240^o $ find $\angle PSQ$
(Answer:$30^o $)

I was unable to find much information for resolution;
$\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{PNQ}  = 240^o \implies \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{PMQ}  = 360^o - 240^o = 120^o $
$AP=AQ$
$MPNQ$ is cyclic
$\angle PNQ =\frac{120^o}{2} = 60^o \implies \angle QMP = 120^o $

I suppose $PSQ$ is an angle, not an arc.

@Intelligentipauca thanks for the alert..corrected

Let $A$ be the left endpoint of the base diameter. If you can show that $AS=AP=AQ$ then you're done.

AP = AQ are tangents..Nedd find AS


Note that $\angle KQP = \frac{1}{2} \overparen{PNQ} = 120^\circ.$ Since $[O_1 Q] \perp [AK]$, we have $\angle O_1QP = \angle O_1PQ = 30^\circ.$ Also, $\angle PQA = 60^\circ$ and $AQ = AP \implies \triangle APQ$ is an equilateral triangle.
Let $O_1 Q = r$ and $OK = R$. And note that $PQ = QA = AP = r\sqrt{3},$ $OQ = AQ - AO = r\sqrt{3} - R,$ $OO_1 = ON - O_1N = R - r.$
In $\triangle OO_1 Q$:
$$
\left( r\sqrt{3} - R \right)^2 + r^2 = \left( R - r \right)^2 
\implies R = \frac{3r}{2 \left( \sqrt{3} - 1 \right)}.
$$
Since $\angle MO_1 R = 15^\circ$, in $\triangle MO_1R$, we have $RM = RP = \tan{15^\circ} r = \left(2 - \sqrt{3}\right)r.$ Also, in the rectangle $HM'O_2 T$, we have $O_2 T = M'R + RM + MH.$
Let $O_2 N' = r'.$
Additionally, $OO_2 = ON' - O_2N' = R - r',$ $OT = OQ - HQ + HT = r\sqrt{3} - R - r + r'.$
In $\triangle OO_2T$:
$$
\left( M'R + RM + MH \right)^2 + \left( r\sqrt{3} - R - r + r' \right)^2 = \left( R - r' \right)^2. \tag{1}
$$
In $\triangle O_2 SA$ and $\triangle O_2 AT$ we have the same hypotenuse:
$$
AS^2 + r'^2 = \left( r\sqrt{3} - r + r' \right)^2 + \left( M'R + RM + MH \right)^2. \tag{2}
$$
Using (1) and (2):
$$
x^2 = \left( r \sqrt{3} - r + r' \right)^2 + \left( \frac{3r}{2 \sqrt{3} - 2} - r' \right)^2 - \left( r \sqrt{3} - r - \frac{3r}{2 \sqrt{3} - 2} + r' \right)^2 - \left( r' \right)^2,
$$
we let
$$
a = r \left( \sqrt{3} - 1 \right) \quad \text{and} \quad b = \frac{3r}{2 \left( \sqrt{3} - 1 \right)}.
$$
Then,
$$
\left( a + r' \right)^2 + \left( b - r' \right)^2 - \left( a - b + r' \right)^2 - \left( r' \right)^2.
$$
Using $\left( a + r' \right)^2 = a^2 + 2a r' + \left( r' \right)^2$, $\left( b - r' \right)^2 = b^2 - 2b r' + \left( r' \right)^2$, $\left( \left( a - b \right) + r' \right)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2 + 2a r' - 2b r' + \left( r' \right)^2$,
$$
\left( a^2 + 2a r' + \left( r' \right)^2 \right) + \left( b^2 - 2b r' + \left( r' \right)^2 \right) - \left( a^2 - 2ab + b^2 + 2a r' - 2b r' + \left( r' \right)^2 \right) - \left( r' \right)^2.
$$
So,
$$
= a^2 + 2a r' + \left( r' \right)^2 + b^2 - 2b r' + \left( r' \right)^2 - \left( a^2 - 2ab + b^2 + 2a r' - 2b r' + \left( r' \right)^2 \right) - \left( r' \right)^2,
$$
$$
= a^2 + 2a r' + \left( r' \right)^2 + b^2 - 2b r' + \left( r' \right)^2 - a^2 + 2ab - b^2 - 2a r' + 2b r' - \left( r' \right)^2 - \left( r' \right)^2,
$$
$$= \left( a^2 - a^2 \right) + \left( 2a r' - 2a r' \right) + \left( r'^2 + r'^2 - r'^2 - r'^2 \right) + \left( b^2 - b^2 \right) + \left( -2b r' + 2b r' \right) + 2ab,
$$
$$
= 2ab.
$$
This gives
$$
2ab = 2 \left( r \left( \sqrt{3} - 1 \right) \right) \left( \frac{3r}{2 \left( \sqrt{3} - 1 \right)} \right) = 3r^2.
$$
So
$$
x^2 = 3r^2 \implies x= \sqrt{3} r.
$$
We can see that now,
$$
AS=AP=AQ=\sqrt{3} r.
$$
This means that the points $S$, $P$, and $Q$ lie on a circle with center $A$ and radius $AS=AP=AQ$.
Thus,
$$
\angle PSQ = \frac{1}{2} \angle PAQ = 30^\circ.
$$

Excellent resolution Thank you for your help but I have some questions?
$ [O1O]\perp[AK]$ would not be $ [O1Q]\perp[AK]$
Wouldn't the drawing be to scale since the $\triangle APQ$ is equilateral but in the drawing it doesn't appear to be equilateral?

You are right. It's a typo. I did not scale the drawing; it serves only as a schematic representation. Forgetting to mention that is my apology.

Ok.. I thank you for your help

To better understand this problem, consider the figure below, with a half-circle of centre $O$ and diameter $AB$ and a half-chord $HI$ perpendicular to $AB$. Inscribe in that figure a circle of centre $G$, tangent to $HI$ and to arc $IB$, with tangency points $K$ and $F$.
Note first of all that $\angle BOF=2\angle BAF=2\angle CKF$, implying that $AKF$ are aligned. If $AS$ is a tangent issued from $A$ to the circle, we have then:
$$
\begin{align}
AS^2 & =AK\cdot AF\\
& =AK\cdot(AK+KF)\\
& =AK^2+AK\cdot KF\\
& =AK^2+(IH-HK)\cdot(IH+HK)\\
& =AK^2+IH^2-HK^2\\
& =AH^2+IH^2 \\
& =AI^2
\end{align}
$$
Hence, the length of $AS$ doesn't depend on the position of circle $G$.
Back to your problem, from the above proof it follows that points $SPQ$ in your figure all lie on the same circle with center $A$ and:
$$
\angle PSQ={1\over2}\angle PAQ.
$$
If $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{PNQ}  = 240°$ then $\angle PAQ=60°$ and the result follows.


"Back to your problem, from the above proof it follows that points SPQ  in your figure all lie on the same circle with center A
and:"  Did you use your colleague's demonstration to confirm this?

Awesome solution, +1.

@petaarantes That tangents $AS$, $AP$ and $AQ$ all have the same length $AI$ follows from my proof. Or do you mean something else?

I understood $AS = AI$ but I didn't quite understand why the points $SPQ$ in your figure all lie on the same circle with center $A$.. $AP=AQ$..ok but $AP = AS$ I don't understand?

@petaarantes Because also $=$, as the proof is valid for ANY circle internally tangent.

Do you mean that for any circle inscribed to the right of HI and centered at A, they will all have the same radius that will be tangent to each inscribed circle?

@petaarantes Yes: the distance between $A$ and the tangency point of the inscribed circle is always $AI$, for any circle. Hence you can apply that also to circle $MQN$ in your figure.

thanks my friend for explanation,

It’s worth noting that the diagram as given is impossible (or rather, it cannot fit the situation described). A circle can’t be tangent to the diameter at $Q$, tangent to the half-chord at $M$, tangent to the semicircle at $N$, tangent to $\overline{AP}$ at $P$, and have $\angle PNQ = 60°$.
(I’m not familiar with the notation $\overset{ \LARGE{ \frown }}{PNQ} = 240°$, although its meaning seems plain enough: the arc from $P$ through $N$ to $Q$ spans 240° of its circle. This is equivalent to $\angle PNQ = 60°$, so that’s what I’ve gone with.)
Of course none of these points is explicitly stated to be a tangent point, but the answers as given (which agree with the expected result) rely on that being the case for at least some of them. Specifically, Intelligenti pauca’s answer omits the tangency at $Q$, and then derives a result for a circle centred at a variable point $G$. It is possible to position this circle tangential to the diameter—but that circle will not have the required angle.
Proof
As others have done, let $A$ be the left endpoint of the diameter, and let $H$ be the intersection of the diameter and the half-chord. Also, let $C$ be the centre of the circle tangent to $M$, $N$, and $Q$.
The key point is the ratio between $\left| HM \right|$ and $\left| HO \right|$. Let $\left| HM \right| = 1$ and allow $x := \left| HO \right|$ to vary on $\left( 0, \infty \right)$.

Observe that $CMHQ$ is a square with side length equal to the radius of our circle, which we’ve fixed at 1. $\triangle COQ$ is right-angled at $Q$ with leg lengths $1$ and $x + 1$. Let its hypotenuse be $c := \left| OC \right|$.
Since $N$ is the common tangent point of the circle and the semicircle, $O$, $C$ and $N$ are collinear, so $\angle COQ = \angle NOQ$, and the radius of the semicircle is $\left| ON \right| = c + 1$.
Observe also that $\tan \angle COQ = \frac{1}{x+1}$, and so $\angle COQ$ is strictly decreasing as $x$ increases. Specifically, its bounds are $\angle COQ \to 0°$ as $x \to \infty$, and $\angle COQ \to 45°$ (the diagonal of the square) as $x \to 0$.
Conversely, $c$ is strictly increasing as $x$ increases, with a minimum of $\lim_{x \to 0} c = \sqrt{2}$.
Similarly, $\triangle CAQ$ is right-angled at $Q$ with leg lengths $1$ and $c + x + 2$. Like $\angle COQ$, $\angle CAQ$ is strictly decreasing as $x$ increases, with $\lim_{x \to \infty} \angle CAQ = 0°$.
What about as $x \to 0$? It’s plain that $\angle CAQ < \angle COQ < 45°$, but we’re going to need a tighter bound: specifically, we need to show that $\angle CAQ < 30°$. We could stick to synthetic geometry to prove this, but here I find it’s easier to go analytic for a moment:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} c = \sqrt{2} \\\\
\therefore \lim_{x \to 0} \angle CAQ &= \arctan \left( \frac{1}{2 + \sqrt{2}} \right) \\\\
&\approx 16.325°
\end{align}
$$
A point exterior to a circle is the intersection of two tangents to the circle, and is equidistant from both tangency points. So $A$ is equidistant from $P$ and $Q$, meaning $\triangle APQ$ is isosceles, with $AC$ as its axis of symmetry.
One consequence of this is that $\angle PAQ = 2 \angle CAQ$, and so $0 < \angle PAQ < 32.650°$.
Another consequence is that $APCQ$ is a kite, with edge lengths $\left| CP \right| = \left| CQ \right| = 1$ and $\left| AP \right| = \left| AQ \right| = c + x + 2$. Thus, $\angle PCQ = 180° - \angle PAQ$.
Chord $PQ$ subtends twice the angle at $C$ that it does at $N$, on the circle’s circumference. That is, $\angle PNQ = \frac{1}{2} \angle PCQ = 90° - \frac{1}{2} \angle PAQ$.
We want $\angle PNQ = 60° \Leftrightarrow \angle PAQ = 60°$. But this contradicts $0 < \angle PAQ < 32.650°$, and so the construction is impossible. ∎
